# primeng p-upload icon is just wrong

Tags: angular, icons, primeng

Hello any one have any idea why the icon is presenting itself like that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question. I assume you're using something called [primeNG](https://primefaces.org/primeng/)?

Seems like it could be something related to not properly setting things up. Did you add all of your css files to your angular.json? Did you follow the primeng [setup](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup) correctly?

Comment: Hello Chano, apologies about the vagueness of my question but I assumed the subject of my line (primeng) was enough?, yes I am using primeng, I installed an old version and installed the newest version and everything seems to be okay (the icons below are showing correctly) is only that cancel icon that is showing like that. why will any one downvote my question?

Comment: It's more so vague in the whole question rather than the fact that you are using primeng. That's probably why someone downvoted. It doesnt follow stack overflow guidelines. This shows no code, it doesn't show what youve tried already, and it doesn't describe the problem in detail.